# Vuex State watch over Compute not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have empty state in the beginning like so

```
new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    comboBoxNewValues: {}
},
```

Over time, there are mutations which changes the state like so

```
this.$store.commit('addComboBoxValues', { input: 'foo', value: ['value': 1, 'name': 'bar']});
```

Using the following mutation code

```
 mutations: {

    addComboBoxValues(state, _value) {
        state.comboBoxNewValues[_value.input] = _value['value'];
    },
}
```

It works perfectly and mutations also changes the state, Now I want to perform some action on change of the state so in my component I added a computed property like so

```
computed: {
    getComboBoxNewValues() {
        return this.$store.state.comboBoxNewValues;
    }
}
```

When I debug using vue-dev-tools, the components computed property has data. Whenever the data changes using mutation in the vuex, that data is reflected in the computed property as well.

Now I add a watcher to it like so

```
watch: {

    getComboBoxNewValues:{

        handler: function(to, from) {
            console.log("reload");

        },
        deep: true
    }

}
```

The problem is that the never never gets called, no matter how many times the data has changed in the computed property. Please advice on what I am missing.

Comment: You're adding new properties to an object which is **not reactive**. Use `Vue.set(state.comboBoxNewValues, _value.input, _value.value)`

Comment: Thanks that work. Can you explain a bit more about it?

Comment: See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules